# How to run built-in Sound Recorder?

Tags: applications, stock-android

If you go to `Settings -> Apps -> All`, you'll be able to find the "Sound Recorder" built-in application in JB 4.2.2, but it's not shown on the app drawer.

Curious, how to run it?!

PS: it's not a question about choosing recording application, but about curiosity of running the built-in one

[image: sound recorder app info]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the `Sound recorder` could be just a component that is used by several apps, such as `Google Now` and `Voice Search`. If you take a look at the list of apps, there are also others that can't be run directly, such as `MusicFX`, `NFC Service`, `Search Applications Provider` etc., most of which take exactly the same amount of space, 12.00KB.

Note that this is just an assumption, I have no further proof.

Comment: Yep, I actually came into the same conclusion, but was looking for some proofs or just similar thoughts

Comment: But, huh, they could choose the better name for the service (who I am to judge though)

Comment: It's launchable, there are apps in gplay store to open the activity. Can't confirm that they are working, using lollipop

Answer (score 8):

This app has no inbuilt GUI link on many builds. You can use the app [Sound Recorder Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kayan.nurav.soundrecorder) by KN Inc to access it through a shortcut though. The app needs no permission. The recordings are saved on the SD card in path `/sdcard/`. The files names are `recording*.3gpp`. The recording was just ok though with some amount of background noise.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to record with the help of built in app. Go to `Messaging app->Attach->Record Audio`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to run it:

1. Open your app list.
2. Go to *Voice Recorder*.
3. Open it and record.

Comment: There is no either "Voice Recorder" or "Sound Recorder" in "app list"

Comment: Are you in stock 4.2 or is a custom ROM? *Voice Recorder* should be in a stock ROM.

Comment: I'm on a vanilla JB 4.2.2 shipped with Nexus 4

Comment: I think Nexus 4 doesn't have it preinstalled. Does it have something like "Google Voice" or something similar?

Comment: Nope, there is no Google Voice. And I've added a screenshot of a app details taken from "App > All > Sound Recorder"

Answer (score 2):

There must be an .apk floating around somewhere.  My CyanogenMod 4.2.2 has an app in the drawer named "sound recorder".