# Certain applications icons are missing in Nova Launcher

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.3-jelly-bean, nova-launcher

I have [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) (Prime version) installed on my Galaxy Nexus phone and I have noticed, that some of applications are missing in this launcher. In particular:

- Voice Search, and
- Sound Recorder

I can see these applications in `Settings > Apps > All`:

[image: Apps Settings]

and in Google Play, but there is no sign of them in Nova Launcher. Icons to these applications are not present in NL's menu (app drawer), not on any of desktops and I can't even add them to desktop because, when long-pressing desktop and selecting `Add to Home Screen > Apps`, neither of these applications is listed on application list:

[image: Add Apps]

When I open up my app drawer in Nova Prime, I also can't see these apps. Notice, that I don't have `Apps` and `Widgets` tabs in my app drawer, because I have modified these. I've added my own tabs and removed `Widgets` tab, which I don't use at all. However, what concerns me the most, is the fact, that my app drawer contains different menu options in context menu than in case of other users (see [*geffchang*'s answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/96754/20449) as reference). I have `Play Store` and `Nova Settings`:

[image]

While other have `Show Hidden Apps` and `Edit Tab...`. This, however, is just a strange issue (and possible a clue), but doesn't change much, because, if I go to `Nova Settings > Drawer > Hide Apps` and select `Show Hidden Apps` from context menu, then my `Hidden Apps` list still does not contain these two, I'm looking for (`Voice Search` and `Sound Recorder`). This list contains only these applications, that I see in `Add to Home Screen > Apps` list.

I have absolutely no idea, why I can't see these two applications in any of Nova Prime lists and how to add them to either home screen or app drawer. Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a developer, I believe it's because there are no GUI that are set to appear on the launcher (example: "Contacts Storage" only stores contacts, and it's shown as an *app* in "All" apps).

This is backed-up by [dez93_2000's answer on another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46723/44325),

> This app has no inbuilt GUI link on many builds. You can use the app [Sound Recorder Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kayan.nurav.soundrecorder) by KN Inc to access it through a shortcut though. [...]

So, you have to install other apps as a shortcut to these apps that don't have launcher on their own:

- Sound Recorder: [Sound Recorder Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kayan.nurav.soundrecorder) (as mentioned on the answer)
- Voice Search: [ICS Voice Search Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.companion.VoiceShortcut) (donation-ware)

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, because it brings argument, that may actually explain everything here. If app has no GUI, then putting icon / shortcut to it may be pointless. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

They are probably hidden.

If you go to `Nova Settings` > `Drawer` > `Hide Apps` do you see them listed there with ticks next to them? If so, un-tick them and they will re-appear in the drawer.

Comment: No, this is not the case. I have a long list of apps there, but none of them is checked. I don't think, this could be the case, because -- if I get it right -- this controls only apps in drawer. This would not explain, why these apps are also missing from `Add to Home Screen > Apps` list.

Comment: On my phone apps are hidden from `Add to Home Screen` > `Apps` if they're in that list. There is a 'Show hidden apps' button at the bottom of the `Add to Home Screen` > `Apps` list on my device too.

Comment: Hm... strange. I had `Show hidden apps` option only in `Nova Settings > Drawer > Hide Apps`, you mentioned first, in three-dot context menu. Selecting this option does not changed anything (list get longer, but again, no apps were checked as hidden). I don't have `Show hidden apps` button at the bottom of the `Add to Home Screen > Apps` (I have only apps list and `Select Multiple` button), which is odd, as I seems to have newest version of Nova Launcher Prime.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to hijack [bmdixon's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/96702/5342).

What do you see on your app drawer? Do you see the (blue) APPS and WIDGETS tab? If not, then maybe Nova launcher is not active launcher.

[image]

Comment: When I open my app drawer, I don't see `Apps` and `Widgets` tabs, because I have already configured Nova Prime to suit my needs. I have five my own custom tabs and I have turned off `Widget` tab at all. When I tap three-dot menu button in app drawer, I can see `Nova Settings`, which assures me, that I'm actually using Nova Prime as main launcher! :> However, what concerns me the most, is that I don't see context menu items, you have on your screenshot, i.e. `Show Hidden Apps` and `Edit Tab...`. Instead, I have: `Google Play` and `Nova Settings`. This case begins to be really weird.

Comment: @trejder Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Sir, yes, sir! :> Take a look at [an updated question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/96701/20449). Thanks.

Comment: @trejder I see your problem. You're clicking on the wrong button - the three dots (aka overflow button). You need to click on the tab (e.g. MAIN, INTERNET, FUN, TAB). Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, because you're right, that I was tapping in wrong place. After tapping on tab itself I found your options and checked `Show Hidden Apps`. No, because after doing this, I still can't see neither `Sound Recorder` nor `Voice Search` icons. For some reasons these two apps (maybe more) are completely not seen anywhere within Nova Prime and I can only list them in system level (in system settings). So, we're going back to my initial question -- what can be causing, that Nova Prime does not have any access to certain system apps and does not list them anywhere?

Comment: Plus: I wasn't too much surprised, that I can't see these two apps after checking `Show Hidden Apps`, because I've been to Nova's hidden apps list many times, from different points (for example from `Nova Settings > Drawer > Hide Apps`, suggested by @bmdixon). I can't even search them in app drawer, while app drawer's search goes through all icons, Nova have access to, no matter if they're hidden or not. As in previous comments, for some reason unknown to me, Nova doesn't see these two apps anywhere within itself. They're accessible only on system level.